# AttributeError: function 'GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx' not found

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pytest

That's what I get when I try to run pytest on windows.

Any ideas?

Can't find anything in google.

Maybe, it is a problem with 32/64 bit or missing package?

Really see this error first time and it appears that there is problem with ctypes.

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\py.test.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 47, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 132, in _preparec
onfig
    pluginmanager=pluginmanager, args=args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py", line
 724, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py", line
 338, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py", line
 333, in <lambda>
    _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py", line
 595, in execute
    return _wrapped_call(hook_impl.function(*args), self.execute)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py", line
 249, in _wrapped_call
    wrap_controller.send(call_outcome)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\helpconfig.py", line 32, in pytest
_cmdline_parse
    config = outcome.get_result()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py", line
 279, in get_result
    _reraise(*ex)  # noqa
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py", line
 264, in __init__
    self.result = func()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py", line
 596, in execute
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 880, in pytest_cm
dline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 1030, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 1001, in _prepars
e
    args=args, parser=self._parser)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py", line
 724, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py", line
 338, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py", line
 333, in <lambda>
    _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py", line
 595, in execute
    return _wrapped_call(hook_impl.function(*args), self.execute)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\vendored_packages\pluggy.py", line
 244, in _wrapped_call
    next(wrap_controller)   # first yield
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py", line 35, in pytest_lo
ad_initial_conftests
    _readline_workaround()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py", line 481, in _readlin
e_workaround
    import readline  # noqa
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\readline.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyreadline.rlmain import Readline
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\__init__.py", line 17, in <modu
le>
    from . import unicode_helper, logger, clipboard, lineeditor, modes, console
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\__init__.py", line 15,
in <module>
    from .console import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\console.py", line 177,
in <module>
    L[name] = func = getattr(k32, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 378, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 383, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx' not found
```

Comment: Add information about the system you are running your code on.

Comment: Are you running pytest with the pdb option? https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1388

Comment: What is python version and is it 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: It might be missing from `ctypes` and you didn't say what Windows version.